# Looping through form controls using UseCompatibleTextRendering

Tags: vb.net, forms

I am trying to find a way to use the **UseCompatibleTextRendering** properties on each control on my form. However, it does not seem to be an option when i use the following code below:

```
For Each ocontrol As Control In Form1.Controls
    ocontrol.UseCompatibleTextRendering = True
Next
```

**ocontrol** does not seem to have that option but has all other options for the button. If i do **Buttion1.UseCompatibleTextRendering = True** then it works just fine.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

It is not a property of Control.  Only Button, CheckListBox, GroupBox, Label, LinkLabel and PropertyGrid have the property.  There's a good reason for that, only those controls display text that's rendered by Winforms instead of Windows.

Do consider that this property only exist to keep compatibility with apps that were started back in .NET 1.x.  It is very unusual to want to fall back to GDI+ text drawing when you've got TextRenderer.  Which renders text the same way as native Windows controls, like TextBox, ComboBox, ListView, TreeView, etc.

You'll want to set the application's default instead of setting it for every control.  Project + Properties, Application tab, click the "View Application Events" button.  Make the class look like this:

```
Partial Friend Class MyApplication
    Protected Overloads Shared ReadOnly Property UseCompatibleTextRendering() As Boolean
        Get
            Return True
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```